# MySQL as a simple Mac application for development

Tags: macos, mysql, development

What is the easiest way to run MySQL for development purposes on the Mac?

Ideal would be a server embedded in a Mac application, that starts when you press a start button, and stops when you quit the app.

I do not need a background service running, I do not want to have to be an admin user to install or run, I do not want to see a command line, I do not want to edit configuration files, I do not want files spread out all over the disk (everything should be in the App bundle and the Documents folder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) may work for you.

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: Okay, that was easy. Unfortunately, I also need DBD::Mysql, and it seems that does not build against MAMP. I think I am going VirtualBox/Linux :-(

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use MySQL, but I believe you should use [libmysqld](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/libmysqld.html):

> The embedded MySQL server library
>   makes it possible to run a
>   full-featured MySQL server inside a
>   client application. The main benefits
>   are increased speed and more simple
>   management for embedded applications.
>
> The embedded server library is based
>   on the client/server version of MySQL,
>   which is written in C/C++.
>   Consequently, the embedded server also
>   is written in C/C++. There is no
>   embedded server available in other
>   languages.
>
> The API is identical for the embedded
>   MySQL version and the client/server
>   version.
>
> The embedded MySQL server library is
>   NOT part of MySQL 5.0. It is part of
>   previous editions and will be included
>   in future versions, starting with
>   MySQL 5.1.

Comment: sorry, misunderstanding. I do not want to embed MySQL in my app. It will use regular network connections to talk to a MySQL server. I just want to have a hassle-free MySQL server on my development machine.

Comment: Actually, in my case, I am developing a Perl program, using DBD::SQLite, and when it is done, switch to MySQL. If someone could package libmysqld into DBD::libmysql, that would do the trick ;-)

Comment: In that case, you might be interested in the DBD::mysql, found at http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dbi.html

Answer (score 0):

MAMP seems to be the easiest way to go for a MySQL server.

Unfortunately, it does not have Perl support, and building the Perl client on the Mac is a pain (maybe macports is the solution here), so I went with VirtualBox and [Turnkey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/)'s MySQL appliance (and put the Perl client inside there as well). Not too huge a download, starts fast, database and nice admin pages (phpMyAdmin) preconfigured.

Comment: Perl's already installed on Mac OS X.

I successfully used MAMP for some MediaWiki related work, it was very handy.

Comment: Perl is installed, but not DBD::mysql